# AppEngine Datastore Asynchronous put

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore

In http://blog.notdot.net/2010/09/Under-the-hood-with-App-Engine-APIs, it explains how you can perform an asynchronous datastore get request. I want to perform an asynchronous put request.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of GAE 1.5.0 there is '[put_async](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#put_async)'.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option for doing asynchronous calls to the datastore at the moment is to use Guido's experimental [NDB project](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/), which is a reworking of the App Engine datastore API to support asynchronicity.

My blog post was intended to be instrucitonal, but not as a template for something to do directly - reaching down to that level of the code to do asynchronous requests is likely to be very involved and awkward, and you're much better using a library that does it for you, like NDB.